# Validation.ErrorChangedHandler is not called on TextBlock in WPF DataGrid

Tags: .net, wpf, validation, datagrid

I have a pretty simple DataGrid binded to a collection of custom object. Custom object is annotated with DataAnnotations and impletented IDataErrorInfo.

```
public class MyObject : IDataErrorInfo {
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Amount_Required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
    [Range(typeof(decimal), "0", "1000000000", ErrorMessageResourceName = "InventoryCost_Amount_Invalid", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
    public decimal? Amount { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Name_Required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessageResourceName = "Name_MaxLength", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // standard IDataErrorInfo stuff here
 }
```

I'd like that DataGrid validates any object inside it and I'll be able to detect in code if object is correct or not. I tried the following way:

1. Add collection of all validation error in UserControl

   ```
   private readonly List<Tuple<object, ValidationError>> errors = new List<Tuple<object, ValidationError>>();
   ```
2. Add validation handler in UserControl's constructor:

   ```
   Validation.AddErrorHandler(this, ErrorChangedHandler);
   ```
3. Handle validation changed:

   ```
   private void ErrorChangedHandler(object sender, ValidationErrorEventArgs e)
   {
       Debug.WriteLine(e.Action.ToString() + ":object=" + e.OriginalSource.ToString() + ",error=" + e.Error.ToString());
       if (e.Action == ValidationErrorEventAction.Added)
       {
           errors.Add(new Tuple<object, ValidationError>(e.OriginalSource, e.Error));
       }
       else
       {
           Tuple<object, ValidationError> error = errors.FirstOrDefault(err => err.Item1 == e.OriginalSource && err.Item2 == e.Error);
           if (error != null) { errors.Remove(error); }
       }
       bool hasError = !errors.Any();
   }
   ```

This works correct if I edit **existing** object, but if I try **add** new object, error changed event flow is very strange: validation errors for TextBlock are added at the time new object is created and never removed, even after I put correct values for all two fields. Here is my log (I logged all validation errors):

```
(I created new row,i.e. object)
```

Added:object=System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock,error=System.Windows.Controls.ValidationError
    Added:object=System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock,error=System.Windows.Controls.ValidationError
    Added:object=System.Windows.Controls.TextBox,error=System.Windows.Controls.ValidationError
    Added:object=System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell,error=System.Windows.Controls.ValidationError
    Removed:object=System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell,error=System.Windows.Controls.ValidationError

```
(I put correct value for Name field)
```

Removed:object=System.Windows.Controls.TextBox,error=System.Windows.Controls.ValidationError
    Added:object=System.Windows.Controls.TextBox,error=System.Windows.Controls.ValidationError
    Added:object=System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell,error=System.Windows.Controls.ValidationError

```
(I put correct value for Amount field, now object (and whole row is the grid) is valid)
```

Removed:object=System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell,error=System.Windows.Controls.ValidationError
    Removed:object=System.Windows.Controls.TextBox,error=System.Windows.Controls.ValidationError

But first two errors related to TextBlock are not removed, so list of all error is not empty and hasError variable in ErrorChangedHandler is false.
My XAML is pretty simple too:

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="grid"
              ItemsSource="{Binding MyObjects}" 
              CanUserDeleteRows="False" Margin="11,11,11,11" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              Height="308">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, 
                                ValidatesOnExceptions=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}" 
                                Header="Name" Width="100" ElementStyle="{StaticResource TextCellElementStyle}"
                                EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource TextCellEditingStyle}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Amount, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, 
                                ValidatesOnExceptions=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}" 
                                Header="Amount" Width="75" ElementStyle="{StaticResource TextCellElementStyle}"
                                EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource TextCellEditingStyle}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```